# Hikari keeps polling our serverless database?

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, hikaricp

We have a Spring Boot application usin AWS Aurora serverless as a database. Our back-end is 99% of the time not used; therefore, we set the minimumidle parameter to 0 - hoping that Hikari would after a certain amount of time, close all the connections until they're needed again. That way our serverless database would also pause after a certain amount of inactive time.

Unfortunately, it's not working. We can see that Hikari is indeed closing the idle connections as we monitor our database. However, our serverless database isn't pausing due to inactivity.

My question is: Is Hikari is doing periodical polling to the database at certain intervals even after no idle/active connections are left? We suspect this is what's keeping our DB "active".